# How *should* this content be rendered when h-scrolling is introduced?

Tags: html, css, web-standards

Given markup [like this](http://jsbin.com/asaza):

```
<body>
  <div style='text-align:center'>header</div>
  <table>
    <tr><td>
      really_wide_table................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

How should it be rendered if the table is so wide that horizontal scrollbars are introduced?

Should the header div be centered in the left-most visible screen, or centered above the table? Or something else?

Note: I know what [*does*](http://jsbin.com/asaza) happen, what I'm looking for is an official reference that defines what *should* happen (I ran into [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595995/how-do-i-keep-divs-from-resizing-in-ie6)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `div` is a block element and by definition has its default `width` set to `100%` of it's parent container. The parent container in this case is the visible part of the browser window.

So no matter how wide (or how narrow; try it) the table below (or any element for that matter), the `div` will still fill 100% of the visible browser window.

Since the `div` is as wide as the window, it will appear centered in the window.

I don't have any "official" reference to this but I do know this is how the DOM and CSS specifications work.

Comment: I'll second that.  If you want something to appear centered to the size of the table, it will need to be inside the table.