# Jqgrid with Quirks Mode - Grey area on top

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid, quirks-mode

Can someone help me with this.

I have a webpage that needs quirks mode active to work properly, very old page, but when using jqgrid "edit" or "view" modes i get a huge grey area on top of the page.

[print screen](http://s30.postimg.org/5nwwvredd/Untitled.png)

As soon as i touch the edit button the top part of the page gets this blank space and the edit form is moved there.

Is there a way a go around this issue? Either by removing this grey area, or by setting the edit windows to open in a specific place of the webpage.

Thanks

PS: If i disable quirks this part works well, but the rest of the page gets "crazy"!

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? Which web browser (in which version) you need to support? You wrote "i touch the edit". So you mean Touch screen (Windows on Tablet PC, iPad or some other)? Do you really [quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) (simulation of retro version IE5) or you use wrong terminology?

Comment: Using IE8, really with quirks mode. By touch, i meant click. jqGrid  3.8.2

Comment: What about other questions? **Which version of jqGrid you use?** Do you use any `<!DOCTYPE html ...>` on the page? Probably you mean Compatibility Mode of IE? Quirks mode means that you have HTML page **without any** `<!DOCTYPE html ...>` which means simulation of IE5 published more as 16 yeas ago (in March 1999).

Comment: using jqGrid 3.8.2, but also tried with 4.1.1. And unfortunately, it's not compatibility mode, it really is Document Mode IE5 Quirks. Very old Webpage, that has been update, but some parts...

Comment: Sorry, but you go in wrong direction I think. You should fix your page ("the rest of the page") so that it will be shown in standard CSS. Quirks mode is really dad. It is even before introduction of CSS1. Even retro versions of jQuery and jQuery UI don't support Quirks mode. jqGrid 4.0.0 includes test for quirks mode (`document.documentMode <= 5`) to break processing, but already more old versions of jqGrid (like 3.8.2) works incorrectly in quirks mode. It's better that you include the whole HTML page, explain exactly which part of `the rest of the page gets "crazy"` and fix it.

Comment: Just to be clear: jQuery does not support quirks mode. It never has done and never will do. If you get it working at all in quirks mode you should consider yourself lucky, but it will never work properly. The same would hold for any jQuery plugin. In short, you are never going to get this working. End of story.

Comment: @Spudley I got lucky ;) Everything but popup's were working fine (or sth close to that) I ended up just overwriting all the popup's(add, edit, view and 'no option selected')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep divs from resizing in IE6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595995/how-do-i-keep-divs-from-resizing-in-ie6)